# How do I integrate global javascript into angular?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, branch.io

Specifically, I am using Ionic. I'm having issues with a global function which is being called before the device is ready. How do I move the data from the global javascript function into Angular and prevent this race condition?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. This example is specific to https://branch.io/, but it allows me to have a global javascript function and push data into angular using `injector()`.

## Global DeepLinkHandler into Angular

> listen to Branch data in a global function, save to an angular `DeepLink` factory

```
// a global function
function DeepLinkHandler(data) {
  if (data) {
    // access the angular Factory('DeepLink')
    angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-app]')).injector().get('DeepLink').set(data);
    console.log('Data Link handler response: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
  } else {
    console.error('Data Link handler no data');
  }
}
```

> angular `DeepLink` factory

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('DeepLink', function($window, $timeout) {
  var data = {};

  return {
    get: function() {
      return data;
    },
    set: function(json) {
      // use the angular version of timeout
      $timeout(function() {
        // set the data
        data = json;
        // navigate example
        $window.location = "#/tab/chats/3";
      }, 0);
    }
  };
});
```

> access angular `DeepLink` Factory

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, DeepLink) {
  $scope.content = {}
  $scope.buttonPressed = function() {
    // put branch data into a label that has ng-model content.data
    $scope.content.data = JSON.stringify(DeepLink.get());
  };
})
```